# How would you solve this alternating series problem using the remainder formula?

Tags: calculus

> Determine how many terms of the following convergent series must be summed to be sure that the remainder is less than $10^{-6}$. $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{{}(-1)^k}{k^5}$$

I am unsure of what steps to take to solve this problem. How is the alternate series test related to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not see how to solve the inequality, I will continue.

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(N+1)^5}\le \frac{1}{10^6}\\
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(N+1)^5\ge10^6
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
N+1\ge10\sqrt{10}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
N\ge31
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

In an alternating series the error in stopping the sum at the $N$th term is less than or equal to the absolute value of the $(N+1)$st term, so you want to solve
$$\frac{1}{(N+1)^5}\le \frac{1}{1000000}$$